# Iterator nested typedefs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, iterator, typedef

I'm creating a custom iterator type, and the only use case right now is `std::for_each`. But apparently, it's not enough to mimic the pointer interface (I'm only doing forward iteration), there are like, a bajillion nested typedefs. I managed to figure out what to put for `iterator_category`, but I'm having real trouble figuring out what `value_type` and `pointer` and `reference` should be, because, y'know, I'm not building a container here, it's an iterator. Why would `for_each` even want to know or care? All it's going to do is forward said on to another function.

Comment: You could try the [Boost iterator facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#iterator-facade-and-adaptor), which is supposed to make writing iterators easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a type `T` as an iterator, you must ensure that `std::iterator_traits` can be specialized for that type.  That means you either need to provide the five nested typedefs that it defers to by default, or you need to specialize `std::iterator_traits` yourself.  The five nested typedefs it requires are

- **difference_type**, which is some type that can represent the distance between two iterators (e.g., as would be returned by `std::distance`)
- **value_type**, which is the type of the object pointed to by the iterator
- **pointer**, which is the return type of the iterator type's `operator->`.  This doesn't necessarily need to be a pointer type and it doesn't necessarily need to be `value_type*` or `value_type const*`.  For example, if you have an iterator that generates elements, you may not have an object to which you can return a pointer.  In that case, you might return an object that wraps the returned element and overloads `operator->` itself.
- **reference**, which is the return type of the iterator type's `operator*`.  This doesn't necessarily need to be a reference type and it doesn't necessarily need to be `value_type&` (or `value_type const&`).  For example, If you're iterating over an immutable range of integers, you might just return the element by value, for performance reasons.
- **iterator_category**, which must be one of the iterator category tags or a type derived from one of those tags:  `input_iterator_tag`, `output_iterator_tag`, `forward_iterator_tag`, `bidirectional_iterator_tag`, and `random_access_iterator_tag` (all in namespace `std`).  Algorithms can use these to select an optimal algorithm based on the iterator category.

You can't omit any of these; they all have to be defined.  That said, sometimes one or more of the typedefs may not make sense.  For example, if you have an iterator that generates `char` elements on the fly, your iterator may not implement `operator->` (because `char` is not a class type).  In this case, you might consider just using `void` for the `pointer` type, since it should never be used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`value_type` is what your iterator iterates over. If `iter` is an iterator, it's the type of `*iter`. `pointer` is the pointer to that, and `reference` is the reference to that.